# Dockerfile Overriding ENV variable

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

I have a Dockerfile and I'd like to make the API configurable with a default value.

> FROM socialengine/nginx-spa
>
> ENV API_URL localhost:6007

So when I run this image I'd to be able to override the localhost:6007 with something like below:

> docker run -e API_URL=production.com:6007 ui

This doesn't work and I can't find a clear explanation of how to do this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you have described should work just fine.  Given:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM socialengine/nginx-spa
ENV API_URL localhost:6007
$ docker build -t ui .
[...]
```

Consider this:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ui env | grep API_URL
API_URL=localhost:6007
```

Compared to:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -e API_URL='production:6007' ui env | grep API_URL
API_URL=production:6007
```

Passing a `-e VARNAME=varvalue` on the `docker run` command line will override a default set in your Dockerfile.

If you are seeing different behavior, please update your question to show exactly the command you are running and the associated output.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't think that's a valid docker command you've given me. It' tries to build the image ENV.

Comment: Uh, what?  Those are perfectly valid docker commands. Note that the image name in both examples is `ui`.  And those are `docker run` commands, they won't build anything.  They might try to pull an image if you mistype something.

Comment: Interesting, it didn't work but your answer did help me figure out my issue. I tried using the ENV variable in the RUN section when I should be using it as CMD. Sorry for the vague question. +1 for the asciinema.org.