# How to I confirm environment variable sent to docker run command is received?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I am having an issue in which I pass an environment variable to the `docker run` command, but the resulting container is using the default value rather than the value passed.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM  alpine
ENV MY_ENV="default value"
ENTRYPOINT echo "MY_ENV: " $MY_ENV
```

Here's what happens when I build and run it:

```
$ docker build -t temp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  54.78kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> 37eec16f1872
Step 2/3 : ENV MY_ENV "default value"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ba6d797b765
Step 3/3 : ENTRYPOINT echo "MY_ENV: " $MY_ENV
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6fb9530b10b2
Successfully built 6fb9530b10b2
Successfully tagged temp:latest

$ docker run temp -e MY_ENV=test
MY_ENV:  default value
```

As you can see, the output is "default value" but shouldn't I expect to see "test"?

If I run `docker inspect` against the container, it shows that the input was received.

Here are the Env and Cmd values from `docker inspect` under Config:

```
"Env": [
    "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    "MY_ENV=default value"
],
"Cmd": [
    "-e",
    "MY_ENV=test"
]
```

I'm sure it's simple. What am I missing?

Comment: A similar question has the desired outcome in the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334751/dockerfile-overriding-env-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your run command to `docker run -e MY_ENV=test temp`.

I tested this locally and it appears to be treating it as an argument, rather than an option (so ignoring it)

Comment: Wow, facepalm! I thought I was going crazy, thank you!