# Override ENV variable in base docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a base docker image, call it docker-image with Dockerfile

```
FROM Ubuntu
ENV USER default
CMD ['start-application']
```

a customized docker image, based on docker-image

```
FROM docker-image
ENV USER username
```

I want to overwrite USER Environment Variable without changing the base-image, (before the application starts), is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334751/dockerfile-overriding-env-variable

Comment: Well what you did worked on my side. When I tried this `USER` was indeed `username`.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot build another image, as described in "[Dockerfile Overriding ENV variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40334751/6309)", you at least can modify it when starting the container with `docker run -e`

See "[ENV (environment variables)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)"

> the operator can set any environment variable in the container by using one or more -e flags, even overriding those mentioned above, or already defined by the developer with a Dockerfile `ENV`

```
$ docker run -e "deep=purple" -e today --rm alpine env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=d2219b854598
deep=purple   <=============
```

Comment: If the underlying image needs to be modified between registries, the mutate `package` of the [go container registry tool](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/tree/main/pkg/v1/mutate) might be useful

Comment: @danialk Interesting. I was not aware of this. I see it used here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/69979872/6309) and here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53528416/6309)