# go-containerregistry package lists GCR repositories from all projects / organizations

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

I am using the following code to list my `docker` repositories that are available in GCR

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/authn"
    gcr "github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/name"
    "github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/v1/google"
    "github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/v1/remote"
)

func main() {

    auth, err := google.NewGcloudAuthenticator()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(auth)
    registry, err := gcr.NewRegistry("gcr.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    repos, err := remote.Catalog(ctx, registry, remote.WithAuthFromKeychain(authn.DefaultKeychain))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, repoName := range repos {
        fmt.Println(repoName)
    }
}
```

The problem is that despite the fact that I have performed an explicit `gcloud config set project` to a specific project, invocation of the above program will list **ALL** repos of **ALL** organizations and **ALL** projects my `gcloud` has access to.

Is there a way to limit the code above so that it lists the gcr repos of a specific org/project?

Comment: I was checking the [Container Registry API](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/docker-api), and there's no way explained there to do so (seems to only implement the Docker API, which does not understand the concept of projects). There is suggested to migrate to [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker). Is this a change that you can make? Or do you need to use the Google Container Registry?

Comment: Unfortunately this has to be done in GCR...

Comment: I didn't realize this SDK existed. The GCP project in which a GCR repository (not registry) is created are named `[(us|eu|..).]gcr.io/${PROJECT}`. The registry root is `gcr.io`. There's a [`NewRepository`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-containerregistry@v0.7.0/pkg/name#NewRepository) method too that may permit referencing the Project to give you only those images.

Comment: Yes but as a first step I want to list the repositories (so that I can later list the images).

Comment: Projects are a primary resource container in GCP. You'll probably want to enumerate the projects in an Org and then enumerate the content of the repositories (!) using the approach above. You can check whether GCR is enabled in a project but likely easier to just try to enumerate its images. But, this is probably the way you'll have to proceed.

Comment: Note `gcloud config set project` only applies to `gcloud` (CLI) commands not SDKs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please note that `gcloud config set project` only applies to `gcloud` (CLI) commands but not SDKs.

Seems like this SDK only implements the Docker API, which does not understand the concept of projects. The suggestion here is to migrate to [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry). You could easily get a list of the repos of a particular project using the list method of the REST Resource [`projects.locations.repositories`](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1beta2.projects.locations.repositories). Here you can find an HTTP GET example:

`GET /v1beta2/{parent=projects/*/locations/*}/repositories`

---

*This answer was created and edited to make the solution given in the comments more visible to the community*.