# Build angular project in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, dockerfile

i have Angular/Node Project in Gitlab..
I Have Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12 as builder    
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
ENV CI=1
RUN npm ci    
COPY . .
RUN npm run build-web --output-path=/dist
```

this Dockerfile is for **Master** branch , i want if i push code in develop branch, want to define in Dockerfile how to build , for example if i push in develop , in dockerfile want be

```
RUN npm run build-dev
```

How i can do this ? can i use if else statement in dockerfile ? or yaml

Comment: Why would the _command_ be different in a different branch? Make it a matter of _config_, or even better have a single artefact you can configure at _runtime_.

Comment: I don't know specifically about angular, but normally, CI scripts are for building the current branch, and is located in every branch which supports CI. And the build system is responsible for checking out this script (with all the other sources) and calling it

Answer (score 1):

Technically you should use single artefact and have it take the configuration at runtime. We do that using angular & environments with a envsubs script on the launch.

You could also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334751/dockerfile-overriding-env-variable) SO question which makes a good example of it.

We are using:

Inside index.html you add script source to /assets/env.js , which gets pulled on page load from static files inside container (assets) and in container runtime script (ENTRYPOINT) just execute:

```
#!/bin/sh

# window env substitutions
envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/de-DE/assets/data/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/de-DE/assets/data/env.js
envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/en-US/assets/data/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/en-US/assets/data/env.js

exec "$@"
```

which then fills env.js with env.template.js (which has $PLACEHOLDER signs, which are overriden by env variables of container).

and then load it into window object.

And to even make it type safe we created:

```
export interface RuntimeEnvironmentInterface {
  baseUrl: string;
}
```

which then gets global override on the Window object:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    envVariables: RuntimeEnvironmentInterface;
  }
}
```

And inside application's environment settings (environment.prod.ts for angular):

```
export const environment: EnvironmentInterface = {
  production: true,
  api: window.envVariables.baseUrl + '/api/v1',
};
```

We use it in production for almost two years now and it works as a charm  (knocking on the wood)

Answer (score 0):

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      variables:
        SSH_IP: "ad@1.2.3.4.5"
        ENVIRONMENT: "develop"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      variables:
        SSH_IP: "ad@1.2.3.4.5"
        ENVIRONMENT: "production"
```

I achieve this by defining a variable in my CI file that
checks for which environment i'm trying to build, based on the branch i'm committing from (You could change this to fit your situation).

A bit unrelated if you specifically require the image locally, but might be
the solution you're looking for if you're trying to then deploy the image somewhere.

Comment: But when you have Docker File ? and you build command is in Dockerfile not Ci/cd ... i am using ci/cd only to build and push in Docker regsitry